# Do pure math questions with physics notation belong on physics stack exchange?

Tags: discussion, scope

I am learning quantum information/computation, and while reading my textbook, naturally some questions arise. Whenever I am stuck on an exercise or have a doubt I post my question on physics stack exchange. But most of my doubts are purely mathematical and, consequently, I am asked to migrate the question on [math.se]. But most of my doubts, although being mathematical in nature, are formulated in terms of Dirac (braket) notation and thus, when I post the question on math I am often asked to migrate it to physics stack exchange as it involves braket notation. Where  should such questions be posted, which are purely mathematical but involve some physics notation?

Comment: Related: http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/q/164/ and I voted as a duplicate of: http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/q/5713/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following Kyle Kanos' suggestion I'll turn my comment into an answer:

I imagine that most of your questions are linear algebra related, which means it should be perfectly acceptable to post them on math SE, and in order to clarify possible notation issues (those more commonly used in physics), try to add a bit of explanation to the notation you're using so everyone can follow. E.g. if you use the bra-ket notation for an inner product then you can explain as (or simply ref. a link that explains it):

[image]

On the other hand there are a lot of purely linear algebra (mainly QM related) posts on physics stackexchange, e.g. questions about diagonalisation, trace properties, self-adjointness, unitarity, etc. So in principle if you also establish the physical context in your post, it should be fine on physics SE as well (with appropriate choice of tags). There's not really more to it.